# Nested JSON Objects length

Tags: android, json

I have following JSON String.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "city_id": "1",
      "city_name_eng": "Multan",
      "0": {
        "category_id": "1",
        "city_id": "1",
        "category_name_eng": "Mango",
        "0": {
          "product_id": "1",
          "category_id": "1",
          "product_name_eng": "Mango1"
        },
        "1": {
          "product_id": "2",
          "category_id": "1",
          "product_name_eng": "Mango2"
        },
        "2": {
          "product_id": "3",
          "category_id": "1",
          "product_name_eng": "Mango3"
        },
        "3": {
          "product_id": "4",
          "category_id": "1",
          "product_name_eng": "Mango1"
        }
      },
      "1": {
        "category_id": "2",
        "city_id": "1",
        "category_name_eng": "Shoes"
      },
      "2": {
        "category_id": "3",
        "city_id": "1",
        "category_name_eng": "Bank"
      }
    },
    {
      "city_id": "2",
      "city_name_eng": "Lahore",
      "3": {
        "category_id": "4",
        "city_id": "2",
        "category_name_eng": "Food"
      },
      "4": {
        "category_id": "5",
        "city_id": "2",
        "category_name_eng": "Computer"
      },
      "5": {
        "category_id": "6",
        "city_id": "2",
        "category_name_eng": "Mobile"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to have length of JSONObject. Basically, the first object having `"city_id": "1"`  has 4 nested JSONObjects and 2 values, i.e. city_id and city_name_eng.
When i use `objJSON.length()` , it gives me length of 6. But on the contrary I want to have 4 nested JSONObjects, how can i get it on run-time? (whether the nested jsonobjects are 3 or 4 or any number)

How to differentiate between nested JSONObjects and key values?

Comment: Why can't you use JSONArray instead of naming JSONObjects as 0,1,2 etc? That'll make it much more convenient to handle..

Comment: How to do that? I have this JSON Response from a PHP website.
There i used `json_encode(array('data'=>$data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website is your own, then I suggest reworking the code to return `JSONArray`s where appropriate.

Otherwise, `jsonObj.keys()` will return an `Iterator` which you an use to iterate over the keys and parse out your objects.